# Visual Studio and syntax highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

I just installed the [VS Syntax Highlighting pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.SyntaxHighlightingPack)
but now have no idea how to actually apply colored highlighting to existing C# or XML code.

There is no 'Quick start' guide and I have dug through all the menus in VS.

Any VS experts here that might help?

Comment: Syntax highlighting for C# is built into Visual Studio. That extension adds highlighting for languages that are not explicitly supported by VS.  You'll notice C# is not on the list of supported languages on the site you linked to.

Comment: It should be possible to add support for C# there exists a Textmate C# Bundle, and the extension works off the bundles.  Out of the box that particular extension does not support C# though. If thats to much work, I suggest, Resharper for better syntax support.

Comment: could you please post an image of your text editor where it is not performing syntax coloring in C#?  generally those settings are controlled via Tools -> options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors, when "Text Editor" is selected in the dropdownlist at the top of the detail pane.